# What is a maven repository url for jung2 (java graph framework)?

Tags: java, maven-2, repository, jung

I am looking for a maven repository that distributes [jung2](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) packages. Unfortunetely I can not find any information on its location.

Update: 
I have included the cental repository repo1.

```xml
 <repository>
  <id>central</id>
  <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
  <layout>default</layout>
  <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

But I still get an error: 10/4/10 1:31:57 PM CEST: Missing artifact net.sf.jung:jung2:jar:2.0.1:compile. I use Maven 3.0-SNAPSHOT on Mac osX.

Update2: Declaration of Jung2 dependency:

```xml
  <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
                <artifactId>jung2</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>                 
        </dependency>
```

After adding pom, there is no error message. Unfortunetely maven does not retrieve jars of jung2 modules.

[Solved] I have added also a dependency to jung-graph-impl and I can now use jung2 in my project:

```xml
   <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
            <artifactId>jung-graph-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On [repo1](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jung/jung2/) :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

---

**Resources :**

- [mvnrepository.com - Jung 2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jung/jung2)

Comment: Still getting error: 10 1:26:09 PM CEST: Missing artifact net.sf.jung:jung2:jar:2.0.1:compile . Maven3 has download the jung2 pom but not jar files.

Comment: @Skarab, add the `<type>pom</type>` to the dependency, it's not a jar ;)

Comment: Causes error in Eclipse if used as is. Has no errors if configured as `<type>pom</type>`, but also has no effect.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add this to the pom.xml. This work with maven central. No need to specify repository. But you can still use `<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>` directly in your pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
        <artifactId>jung2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
        <artifactId>jung-graph-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

> What is a maven repository url for jung2 (java graph framework)?

Answer: The Central Repository and its mirrors

But generally, you experiencied issue with dependencies.

To make your project buildable with Jung2 library, add specific modules (not `jung2`) to your `pom.xml`.

Example:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
        <artifactId>jung-graph-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
        <artifactId>jung-algorithms</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

See the list of the modules http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jung

---

Adding the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
    <artifactId>jung2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

will not work in the way one could expect.

The reason is declaration of modules inside of profiles in pom.xml for `jung2` artifact:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>all</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>all</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>jung-api</module>
            <module>jung-graph-impl</module>
            <module>jung-algorithms</module>
            <module>jung-io</module>
            <module>jung-visualization</module>
            <module>jung-samples</module>
            <module>jung-jai</module>
            <module>jung-jai-samples</module>
            <module>jung-3d</module>
            <module>jung-3d-demos</module>
    .............
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jung/jung-api) or [Maven Repository Browser](http://www.mvnbrowser.com/artifacts-search.html?page=1&search=jung).